# how to set a keyvault secret across multiple jobs via something parameterized in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to parameterize the task of setting a variable from a keyvault.. so it's easier to use it across my jobs with a different value than the secret itself..

I cannot seem to get the output variable to set correctly at all

```
parameters:
  - name: az_subscription
    type: string
  - name: az_keyvault
    type: string
  - name: secrets_filter
    type: string
  - name: run_pre_job_bool
    type: boolean
    default: false

steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.az_subscription }}
    keyVaultName: ${{ parameters.az_keyvault }}
    secretsFilter: ${{ parameters.secrets_filter }}
    runAsPreJob:  ${{ parameters.run_pre_job_bool }}
  displayName: "Retrieve and set Service Principle (SP) Key"
- bash: |
    echo Start showing...
    echo '$(${{parameters.secrets_filter}})'
    echo $('${{parameters.secrets_filter}}')
    echo 1
    echo "$(${{parameters.secrets_filter}})"
    echo $("${{parameters.secrets_filter}}")
    echo 2
    echo 3
    echo 4
    echo $(hard-coded-secret-filter)  ***this masks properly and is only one that works***
    echo 5
    echo '$(${{parameters.secrets_filter}})'
    echo 6
    echo $(${{parameters.secrets_filter}})
    echo 7
    echo "$(MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR)"
    My_Value=
    echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_VAR;isOutput=true]${{parameters.secrets_filter}}
  name: use_keyvault
  displayName: "Set MY_VAR variable"
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: ${{ parameters.secrets_filter }}
```

how can I get away from hardcoding the $(hard-coded-secret-filter) ? so I can get to use $()

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working here? I'm not sure where the issue is. Are you saying that the `secrets_filter` parameter is blank? If that's the case, then post the YAML of a consuming template that's providing the `secrets_filter` value.

Comment: thanks @DanielMann , basically hardcoded `echo $(hard-coded-secret-filter)` prints out a masked `***` as desired.. signifying I have a vault value I want to protect from getting logged, right?) How can I parameterize this using `$((parameters.secrets_filter}}` to avoid hardcoded names... and apply this value then to an output variable ala `echo ##vso....`

Comment: I still don't understand what you're after here. The `secretsFilter` value is a comma-delimited list of the names of the secrets you want to get from the key vault. The values it retrieves are automatically turned into variables you can access normally. See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops

Comment: @DanielMann , I want to be able to pass in a variable name.. from the parameters.. in order to set the secrets filter.. that works fine when I just .. hard code a string input.  but when I go to attempt to use a string coming from a templated approach it doesn't seem to want to work.. and I get various blanks echo'd out instead of what I want.. the `***` showing masked variable is assigned (which to me is a signal it's a good value from the vault)

Comment: @DanielMann is it easier to .. perhaps use a variable group to pull in things?  ie `Link secrets from an Azure key vault as variables` and move the variable around that way??